# クラス配列の配列を使いたい

Tags: swift

クラスの配列を使用して、INDEXで指定のクラス情報を引き出したいと考えているのですが、
★箇所にてinstance member 'test_1' cannot be used on type 'Otamesi'
と、インスタンスメンバーが使用できないとエラーになってしまいます。
このような使い方はできないのでしょうか。

```
class Otamesi: NSObject {
    class Test :NSObject {
        var test: Int!
        init (test: Int) {
            self.test = test
        }
    }

    private var test_1: Test = Test(test: 1)
    pricate var test_2: Test = Test(test: 2)

    private var test_All: [Test] = [test_1, test2]★
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Otamesi`をインスタンス化している最中に`test_All`プロパティをインスタンス化しようとしているので、エラーが発生しています。

これを回避するには、

```
private var test_All:[Test] {
    get {
        return [test_1, test_2]
    }
}
```

のように`test_All`を **get** を用いて定義することで、
値が必要なときに取得できるようにしましょう。

このようにすれば、
下記メソッドを`Otamesi`に定義した`sampleMethod`を実行したときに、

```
func sampleMethod() {
    for(var i=0; i < test_All.count; i++) {
        print(test_All[i].test)
    }
}
```

問題なく、値が取得できていることがわかると思います。

以上、少しでも参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
早速試してみました。問題なく値の取得ができることを確認できました。
勉強になりました！